# Correct way to implement Facebook Marketing API create new feed call?

Tags: facebook, http, gson

I am attempting to create a new data feed through the Facebook Marketing API. While I have been able to create a new feed, for some reason my URL and Schedule parameter does not get passed over to Facebook, only the name of the feed.

**Code**

```
public static String createNewFeed(String catalogId) throws IOException {

        HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();

        String token = (String) session.getAttribute("FacebookAuthToken");

        URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + catalogId + "/product_feeds?name=WalkerWorks_Product_Feed"
                + "&url=https://www.walkerworks.me/feed.xhtml?user=" + session.getAttribute("dbId")
                + "&interval=hourly&hour=1&access_token=" + token);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader in;
        StringBuffer response = null;
        String input;

        // Creating a BufferedReader and StringBuffer to read connection response.
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        response = new StringBuffer();

        // While there is more information to be parsed, append it to the response
        // StringBuffer.
        while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {

            response.append(input);

        }

        // Close the connection and parse the StringBuffer.
        in.close();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        FacebookUserIDModel model = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), FacebookUserIDModel.class);

        System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());

        return model.getId();

    }
```

Obviously I have the parameters in the URL I am sending to Facebook. I was wondering if I have correctly formatted or created the schedule object. I think that is the only thing I could have wrong as other calls have worked correctly with the exact same url I am sending.

Facebook says this is the requirements for the call:

[Facebook Marketing API / Feed API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3XjR.png)

And here is the created feed. Products are not uploaded and the schedule I set is not created:

[Dynamic Feed Creation on Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3tQp.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank you for reading.

Comment: How different is this from your other question? JSF part is identical, so effectively not really a jsf problem.

Comment: First question was getting the feed and submitting it after the feed was created (at the time, manually through Facebook business manager). This question is actually dynamically creating the feed to set the schedule and the url to grab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to submit the schedule as a json object in the request. This answer is fully functional.

```
public static String createNewFeed(String catalogId) throws IOException {

        HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();

        String token = (String) session.getAttribute("FacebookAuthToken");
        
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/" + catalogId + "/product_feeds?name=WalkerWorks_Product_Feed"
            + "&access_token=" + token);
        
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("schedule={\"url\":\"https://www.walkerworks.me/feed.xhtml?user=" + session.getAttribute("dbId") + "\","
                + "\"interval\":\"hourly\"}");
        
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setEntity(params);
        
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(request.getEntity()));
        
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        /*
         * URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + catalogId +
         * "/product_feeds?name=WalkerWorks_Product_Feed" +
         * "&url=https://www.walkerworks.me/feed.xhtml?user=" +
         * session.getAttribute("dbId") + "&interval=hourly&hour=1&access_token=" +
         * token);
         * 
         * HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         * connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
         * connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); connection.setDoOutput(true);
         * connection.connect();
         */

        /*
         * BufferedReader in; StringBuffer response = null; String input;
         * 
         * // Creating a BufferedReader and StringBuffer to read connection response. in
         * = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
         * response = new StringBuffer();
         * 
         * // While there is more information to be parsed, append it to the response //
         * StringBuffer. while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
         * 
         * response.append(input);
         * 
         * }
         */

        /*
         * // Close the connection and parse the StringBuffer. in.close();
         */

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
        
        FacebookUserIDModel model = gson.fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), FacebookUserIDModel.class);

        return model.getId();

    }
```